# ComboBox in metro app how to get selected text and its related id

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

i have a combo box and sqlite table with columns Id and makeName i want to display Makename and when user select it return me id as seleced value and at the same time i also want to save selected Makename in other table in Metro style app but here i don't find any data text field or data value field type property

Comment: post your relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the Id in the Tag property of the children in the combo-box.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem) . That'll give the actual item that was bound to it. [SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue) is determined by the SelectedValuePath property.

Answer (score 1):

SelectedItem.Content also works `txtBlock.Text = cboTest.SelectedItem.Content`, but `Content` doesn't appear on the VS intellisense for SelectedItem.

[image]

[image]